# Is there a way to determine if a recent wifi network change was user-initiated or not?

Tags: android

My app has behavior that's supposed to initiate when the user manually selects a wifi network. Problem is that I don't know of a way to programmatically determine whether or not a given network change was the result of user choice. Is there a flag that I could access to figure this out?

Comment: I never tried to solve that but what you could probably do is to register a broadcast receiver to listen on [`WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and check if the wifi is the same as previously (means you stores the last wifi name), something like that